# swmr capability of hdf5 and therefore also of h5py

Tags: python, concurrency, hdf5, h5py

I am suffering from a shortcoming of h5py its swmr (single write multiple read) capability as described in an [issue on github](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/712). The issue is labelled with 'bug-in-external-lib' which suggests that the shortcoming is located at the underlying hdf5 library rather than in h5py itself. I wonder if there is any interest from the hdf5 maintainers to change that. Hdf5 has a [bitbucket repository](https://bitbucket.hdfgroup.org/projects/HDFFV/repos/hdf5/browse) with a branch called 'full_swmr'. Does anybody know how mature this branch is? Is there a chance to see full swmr in hdf5 in the nearer future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted the question in the [HDF5 group forum](https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/swmr-capability-of-hdf5/4929/3) and just got a reply that includes answers to both of my questions (thank you Elena).

Concerning the **first question**: the 'full_swmr' branch is stable but it does not resolve the mentioned github issue. Concerning the **second question**: the HDF5 Group is interested in achieving full swmr support. In fact they started to work on a implementation to provide exactly that. This implementation will also resolve the github issue mentioned in the question above. To my understanding the HDF5 Group just kicked the project off and it is not yet foreseeable when the implementation will be made public.